# How does an "auto voltage setting" laptop charger work?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, charger, laptop

I recently came across a very interesting device for me, a laptop adapter that claims it adjusts its output voltage automatically:

https://www.trust.com/en/product/20194-plug-go-universal-90w-laptop-charger-black

The question is obvious: how can it possibly detect the voltage that the target laptop needs? I am planning to buy it but I have concerns over its safety.

Comment: Have you read the manual? That answers your question. (It outputs 16 or 19V depending on which connector you select, so no automatic adjustment)

Comment: *it adjusts its output voltage automatically* "Automatically" meaning that **YOU**, the user, has to select the correct adapter plug. Calling that "automatic" isn't describing the whole truth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no auto detection or other magic. The tip that fits your laptop also selects what voltage the power supply shall output, perhaps with by connecting a certain value resistance between two pins for selecting a certain voltage.

Answer (score 0):

It could start with a low voltage, measure the current drawn by the laptop, and, if that current is very low, raise the output voltage  a little